# Only static members can be accessed in initializers. Grabbing data input as a string, converting to double. Why won't this work?

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

Here's the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();

    xlatitude = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: latitudeController,
    );
  }
  TabController _tabController;
  final latitudeController = new TextEditingController();
  TextFormField xlatitude;
  final double latitudedouble = double.parse(latitudeController.text);
```

How can I get this to convert to double? the latitudeController.text is showing the error: "Only static members can be accessed in initializers."

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation();

    xlatitude = new TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      controller: latitudeController,
    );
     latitudedouble = double.parse(latitudeController.text);
  }

double latitudedouble;
TabController _tabController;
final latitudeController = new TextEditingController();
TextFormField xlatitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. I wasn't placing it in async like so:

```
  Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
    final double n1 = double.parse(latitudeController.text);
    final double n2 = double.parse(longitudeController.text);
    final double n3 = double.parse(longitudeController.text);
    setState(() {
      circles = Set.from([
        Circle(
            circleId: CircleId("none"),
            center: LatLng(n1, n2),
            radius: n3,
            fillColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .5),
            strokeColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 16, 0, .4))
      ]);
//    Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }
```

now it works.